# jQuery issue toggling multiple elements

Tags: jquery, wordpress

## HTML

```
<p>Navigation link 1 <span class="toggle"></span></p>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

<p>Navigation link 2 <span class="toggle"></span></p>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

<p>Navigation link 3 <span class="toggle"></span></p>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>

<p>Navigation link 4 <span class="toggle"></span></p>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

## CSS

```
.sub-menu {
    display: none;
}

span.toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 42px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 7px;
    right: 35px;
    line-height: 42px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

span.toggle::before {
    content: "+";
}

span.toggle.on::before {
    content: "-";
}
```

## JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery( ".toggle" ).click(function() {

        jQuery(this).toggleClass("on");

        if(jQuery(".sub-menu").is(":visible")) {
            jQuery(".sub-menu").css("display", "none");
        } else {
            jQuery(this).next().css("display", "block");
        }

    });

});
```

On the page you can see

Navigation 1
Navigation 2
Navigation 3
Navigation 4

By clicking on the toggle next to each of the navigation elements you get .sub-menu appear. If you press the toggle again, it makes .sub-menu disappear.

Issue #1
If one .sub-menu is already visible, by clicking on another toggle makes the first one disappear, but it doesn't trigger the intended .sub-menu to appear.

Issue #2
If one .sub-menu is already visible, by clicking on another toggle doesn't change the first one back from "-" to "+".

Any ideas how I could fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're code is working as expected, IMO. You're saying:

> "when I click an element with the class 'toggle', toggle whether the
>   clicked element has the "on" class.
>
> Now, if any element with the class "sub-menu" is visible, then hide
>   that. Otherwise (if there aren't any elements with the class "sub-menu" visible)
>   ...show the next element.

Try:

```
$( ".toggle" ).click(function() {
    var $self = $(this);
    var $nextUl = $self.parent().next();
    $('.toggle').not($self).removeClass("on");
    $(".sub-menu").not($nextUl).hide();

    $self.toggleClass("on");
    $self.parent().next().toggle();
});
```

Also, note that you're clicking the `<span>` within a `<p>`, so .next() will find the next element within the `<p>`. You need to move up one level (using `.parent()`), before calling `.next()`.

Checking out a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/daveSalomon/h9c6mavq/).

Comment: Thanks Dave! I do appreciate your help. Just what I needed:)